# VSCode [AI] import suggestions

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode with typescript, and facing a real frustration. Whenever I am passing an object parameter, that is a known type, I press 'ctrl + space' to see the available keys on the object. However VSCode suggest a bunch of crap suggestions and it does my head in.

[image: screenshot of issue]

There are also many suggestions inbetween the valid ones, such as 'Buffer' which also has that blue icon that matches the real keys. It makes finding what is available to me as a parameter impossible.

Anyone got any idea?